# Cannot solve a equation with if-else in python error:cannot determine truth value of Relational

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, equation

I am planning to solve some equations which contain if-else comparisons, but I get the error

```
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

My code is as follows:

```
from sympy import *
import math


b=400*0.0393701;h=600*0.0393701;d=530*0.0393701;
d1=70*0.0393701;fc=24*145.0377439;fy=400*145.0377439;Es = 29000000

# Stage1
Ag=b*h;As=math.pi*((32*0.0393701)**2)/4
ey=fy/Es
peta=0.85

e=[0,200,400,600]

def init(ec,f1, c):
    es = ec*(c-d1)/c
    if es>=ey:
        t=3*As*f1/1000
    else:
        t=3*es*Es/1000
    cc=0.85*fc*peta*c*b/1000
    es1=ec*(d-c)/c
    if es1>=ey:
        cs=3*As*(f1-0.85*fc)/1000
    else:
        cs = 3*As*(Es*es1-0.85*fc)/1000
    res = [cc, cs, t]
    return res

def com(ec, c,k):

    if k==1:   # choose Hognestad modal
        e0=2*0.9*fc/(57000*(fc**(0.5)))  #0.00186
        if ec<=e0:
            fc_1 = 0.9*fc*((2*ec/e0) - ((ec/e0)**2))
        else:
            fc_1 = 0.9*fc*(1-0.15*((ec-e0)/(0.0038-e0)))
        re = init(ec, fc_1, c)

    if k==2:  # choose Collins and Mitchell Model
        k3=0.6+10/24; Ec_rev = 4730*(24**(0.5)); n =0.8 + 24/17
        ec_rev = (24/Ec_rev)*(n/(n-1))
        if ec/ec_rev <=1:
            k_rev = 1
        else:
            k_rev = 0.67+24/62
        fc_2=k3*fc*(ec/ec_rev)*(n/(n-1+((ec/ec_rev)**(n*k_rev))))
        re = init(ec, fc_2, c)

    return re

ec_real=[];
for i in range(0,39):
    ec_real.append(i/10000)

c= Symbol('c')
peta = 0.85
a=peta*c
### Final Solution
M=[]
F=[]
final1={}

for k_final in [1, 2]:
    for x1 in e:
        for x2 in ec_real:
            c_final = solve(com(x2, c, k_final)[0] * (h / 2 - a / 2) + com(x2, c, k_final)[1] * (h / 2 - d1) + com(x2, c, k_final)[2] * (d - h / 2), c)[1]
            Pn = com(x2, c_final, k_final)[0] + com(x2, c_final, k_final)[1] - com(x2, c_final, k_final)[2]
            Mn = Pn * x1
            fai = x2 / c_final
            M.append(Mn);
            F.append(fai)
        ss = {str(x1):{}}
        ss[str(x1)]["M"]=M
        ss[str(x1)]["Fai"]=F
final1 = {str(k_final):{}}
final1[str(k_final)]=ss

print(final1)
```

I run this code and it cannot solve showing that `init()`function has some problems in determinging `if es>=ey:`, the detailed errors shows as follows:

```
    if es>=ey:
  File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 195, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
```

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Comment: Going out on a limb here: what are `type(es)` and `type(ey)`? I suspect `type(ey)`is `float` because it was initialized as `float` divided by `int`, but `es` is initialized with a formula involving `c`, which unless I misread, is of type `Symbol`, so the resulting type may not be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

At the point of failure, `es` is a SymPy object involving `c` and several operations.  You have to cleanly evaluate this before you can compare to the `float` value of `ey`.

```
es =  (0.0001*c - 0.0002755907)/c <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'> 
ey =  0.0020005206055172414       <class 'float'>
```